# Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::prefix()

Tags: php, lumen

I have tried to debug this on my own to no avail and all related questions found have not helped.

I have a Lumen application I cloned from my online repo on GitLab that giving me this error:

**In Facade.php line 239:**

> Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::prefix()

Please how do I fix this?

My Lumen `web.php` route file seems to be working fine as follows:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'agent'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->post('register-worker', 'UserController@registerWorkerByAgent');
    $router->get('workers', 'UserController@getAgentWorkers');
});
```

but the PHP artisan command is still giving me an error. (see image)
[image]

Comment: Does the method prefix() exist in ...\Router.php ?

Comment: I tried locating Router.php but couldn't in my lumen application in the vendor folder there was the laravel/lumen-framework i checked but found no Laravel folder and no Laravel/Lumen folder in the Illuminate folder as well.. so I don't know how to locate that file even

Comment: Did you install the composer dependencies by running composer install? That could be one of the reasons. Although I am not a laravel guy so I can't say for sure.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad Tashfeen. Yes I did composer update after git clone.

Answer (score 0):

For those that may come across this in the future.
I solved this by downgrading my php version to 7.2 from 7.4

As it turns out. Php 7.4 now returns null at the call of some illuminate functions. This was taking care of by downgrading to 7.2. I encountered this problem with a Lumen framework so I anticipate others might have similar issues as well.

Thanks for all the assists. Hope this helps someone.